# use-package and package-initialize problem with emacs27

Tags: package, use-package

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting `use-package` to automatically install packages in emacs27

I deleted a package using `package-delete` and restarted emacs. On emacs26, `use-package` would automatically install the package by connecting to MELPA. But on emacs27, I'm getting the below error:

```
Error (use-package): Failed to install anzu: package.el is not yet initialized!
Error (use-package): Cannot load anzu
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/csraghunandan/.emacs.d/init.el’:

error: package.el is not yet initialized!
```

[Here](https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d) is my emacs configuration
Anybody know how I can fix this issue? Is there anything I need to add to my `early-init.el` file?

Comment: I have this in my early-init.el `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)`. And with that I use the same init.el as before 27 and call `(package-initialize)` in there.

Answer (score 1):

You should report this upstream: the early init of package.el should have taken care of that, so this seems like an upstream bug.  That error comes from package.el itself, originally, simply triggered by use-package interacting with the public interface of the package system.

Comment: This might be [Bug#31397 - Emacs doesn't call package-initialize if there's no elpa directory](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31397).